# How to cherry-pick all commits made by author?

Tags: git

I have `feature` (as example) branch. Then I have `develop` branch which contains unnecessary changes that I don't want in `feature` branch. I found out that I just want to get only my commits from `develop` at some period of time. How can I achieve that? How can I cherry-pick commits from develop made by me only?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
git cherry-pick `git rev-list --reverse --author="AUTHORYOUWANT"  BRANCHYOUWANT | tr '\n' ' '`
```

`git rev-list` finds the commit hashes from the author and branch you specify, line by line, then `tr` combines the lines to one line separated by space which is given as parameter to `git cherry-pick` (it can handle multiple commit hash parameters).

Edit: switched `git log --format=format:%H` to `git rev-list` as suggested in comments, it is more straightforward.

Comment: I would have used `rev-list` since you are just printing the hash (in this way you get rid of `--format`), I am afraid they should be `--reverse`d too.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara I somehow missed rev-list support search by author too, you're right

Comment: You might want `--topo-order` as well, although if you have anything that requires it, cherry-picking those commits might become problematic in the first place. You don't need the `tr` command: the shell's `$(...)` aka backquote processing uses the `$IFS` setting to separate words, and the default IFS is space-tab-newline.